# Java Finding Average with Loop and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random

This is a Java problem I am having, I am somewhat new to Java.

I have to:

1. generate a random fraction
2. keep generating until the sum is greater than 1
3. then I have to display how many numbers I generated and which ones

Here is what I have so far in my function:

```
public static double calcAvg(int numOfTimes){
        double sumOfRand = 0 ;
        int numOffractions = 0;
        double avg = 0;

        double numOfAvg[] = new double[numOfTimes]; // number of rows
        double randNums[] = new double[] {.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9};
        Random rand = new Random();


        for(int i = 0; sumOfRand <= 1; i++){
            int randNum = rand.nextInt(randNums.length); //gets a number from array randomly
                //System.out.println(randNums[randNum]);


            sumOfRand += randNums[randNum]; //adds it to the sum
              numOffractions++; //counts # of avgnums needed for > 1

              numOfAvg[i] = numOffractions; 

        }

        avg = (numOfAvg[0] + numOfAvg[1] + numOfAvg[2]) /(numOfTimes); 

    return avg;
}
```

I keep getting an error on: `numOfAvg[i] = numOffractions;`
and I can't seem to add the fractions to the sum until they pass 1.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you assign `numOfAvg[i] = numOffractions;`?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I'm sure it's `IndexOutOfBounds`, but the problem statement is not clear and he never tells us what `numOfTimes` is supposed to be.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the randNums array. Just generate a random number between 1 and 9 inclusive instead of between 0 and 8.

Comment: The error is the following: `double[] numOfAvg` is initialised with the length `numOfTimes`, but inside the for-loop, `i` is the index, that is adressing the values of  `numOfAvg`. The range of `i` can be very different than the size of `numOfTimes`. This results in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the number of fractions > `numOfTimes`.

Comment: Is your for loop correct ? Your conditional part doesn't have 'i' in it.

Comment: thank you everyone, so numOfTimes is the input in the SPVM of number of times the user wants to see how many fractions it takes for the sum to be > 1

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is not related to your requirements..

You need something like this:

```
public static double calcAvg(){//What is the numOfTimes variable?!
    double randNums[] = new double[] {.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9}; //These can be define outside
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<Double> numbers = new LinkedList<Double>(); // This will have the list of numbers
    double sum = 0;
    while(sum<1){
       int randNum = rand.nextInt(randNums.length);
       numbers.add(randNums[randNum]);
       sum+=randNums[randNum];
    }
    for(Double d:numbers){//Print the numbers
       System.out.println(d);
    }
    System.out.println("Average: ", sum/numbers.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you get array index out of bound when you call the function calcAvg with 1,2,3. 
within the calAvg method you are using the numOfTimes as the array length and accessing numofAvg variable beyond the length range.

The logic needs to be revisited based on your requirement.